# swagger editor UI sends a OPTIONS request method instead of PUT and DELETE

Tags: yaml, swagger-editor

http://editor.swagger.io sends a OPTIONS request method instead of PUT and DELETE but for POST and GET it's work perfectly

even  I have installed a Chrome extension that adds Access-Control-Allow-Origin to outgoing requests. and same added in the c# code like below

[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "x-docname,x-docid")]

```
   put:
  tags:
  - sources
  summary: Updated sources Groups
  description: This Will Create new Group under sources
  operationId: PUT
  consumes:
    - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  produces:
  - application/json
  parameters:
  - name: sourceId
    in: path
    description: name that need to be updated
    required: true
    type: string

  - name: text
    in: formData
    description: Updated name of the text
    required: true
    type: string
  responses:
    200:
      description: "Ok : Successful requests"
    201:
      description: "Created : Successful creation"
    400:
      description: "Bad Request : The path info doesn't have the right format"
    403:
      description: "Forbidden : The invoker is not authorized to invoke the operation"
    404:
      description: "Not Found : The object referenced by the path does not exist" 
    500:
      description: "Internal Server Error : The execution of the service failed in some way"
```

Comment: And what is the problem, exactly? These OPTIONS requests are [CORS preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests), it's part of how CORS works in browsers.

Comment: Actually when we use PUT method request from editor.swagger to server side code(c#), it passed OPTION method instead of PUT  to HttpContext..Request.Method(server side)